# Can anyone give me a simple explanation of how to implement twitter's OAuth in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, oauth

I've found a handful of libraries, which claim to be plug'n'play, but without understanding how OAuth even works, I am not confident in my ability to fix any bugs that arise.

Could someone please just give me an OAuth For Dummies lecture here?

Answer (score 2):

http://oauth.net/code/ scroll down to Objective-C

also here is some code http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of an explanation, similar to this for AES: http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

check http://www.getsharekit.com/install/ it is open source code i guess.

They have implemented twitter using oAuth

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo provides a flowchart that helped me understand how OAuth works:

http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html